# Can we use Adsense in android application using web view

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, android-webview, adsense

I have a website, which has AdSense ads, now I made an android app and integrated the site using web view, now the AdSense ads are also displaying on the app.
So, is it allowed to use these AdSense ads on the android app, or we can only use the AdMob adds

Answer (score 8):

Recently, Google has allowed using Adsense ads in webview (Android and iOS).
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/11893859?hl=en

In Google Mobile Ads SDK version 20.6.0, Adsense support using webview technology has been added. It now allow apps using webview as a primary view to show ads using Adsense in the webview.

You need to integrate [Webview API for Ads - Android](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/webview) or [Webview API for Ads - iOS](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/webview)

For example in Android,

Add dependency in app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.3.0'
}
```

Add following line in AndroidManifest.xml to bypass check for APPLICATION_ID

```
<meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.INTEGRATION_MANAGER"
      android:value="webview"/>
```

In onCreate lifecycle method add following line

```
MobileAds.registerWebView(webView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be used, not in the application but in the webpage. [Explanation](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Ads_in_a_software_application):

> Publishers are not permitted to distribute Google ads or AdSense for
> search boxes through software applications including, but not limited
> to toolbars, browser extensions, and desktop applications. AdSense
> code may only be implemented on web-based pages and approved WebView
> technologies.

Answer (score -1):

AdSense ads are not allowed in Webview. You should only use AdMob for apps.

However, You can use AdX to show ads in webview.